# Add Item to RecyclerView inside Fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a little problem with viewpager and recyclerview.

In my application I have an activity with a viewpager. Inside viewpager I have a number of pages with the same content: a fragment that reach data from web and show that with a recyclerview.
Now, in each fragment I have an edittext with submit button that when is pressed add 1 element to recyclerview.

The problem is that: when submit button is pressed not always the new item is added in the current page (displayed on screen) of viewpager but in other (prev or next).
Works great when viewpager have 1 single page and when, during scroll of pages, the page is reloaded. So maybe the problem is that add the new item in the last page loaded in background and not in the current page.

Do you say how I can fix it?

Thanks